# Displaying data in android

Tags: android, web-services

I have to build an android project which takes input(command) from the user in edittext and returns the output(explanation of command)to the user.I am thinkig of 2 ways to achieve this.
1) store the explanation in sql server 2005 database and use a webservice.
2)Store the explanation in files and retrieve the explanation.
3)Store the explanation in strings.xml file.
I want to ask that which one of the three ways would be simpler and easy.
Moreover to retrieve data from sql server 2005 i will need a webservice.I have never used a webservice.Can someone guide me whether i should use a webservice and sql server 2005 or use files.
But the problem is if i use files for storing explanation i will not be able to regularly modify the files.Is there a way to do so?
Can someone also give me the code samples of sql server 2005 and webservice use in android.

Comment: please elaborate more on what you are going to store in the database, I mean what kind of data? If it is simple stuff then an sqlite database would suffix.

Comment: the user will enter unix commands in edittext and he will get the explanation of the commands in short as the output.

Comment: The unix commands usually do not change so the answer provided below is good. Store your query and text in an XML file and parse to find the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are right if you hardcode the explanations locally you could not change them overtime (until an update is made), however I think using a webservice is a little too much, but if you want to, there are several tutorials online about ASP/.Net webservices + SQL Server.

What you could do is just make an XML file with all the explanations and have it online, so you application can parse it whenever it needs (without SQL nor websvcs).

Comment: Wil net be required for that?

Comment: you can store the XML file locally in your app! (if changes are needed to can release an update)

Comment: Oh I see, I think I missunderstood the question, well, you could do this: save an sqlite DB in the SD card of the user where you have all the possible commands and comments, when you have an update to the sqlite DB just send a push through GCM, and make the app retrieve the new sqlite DB from internet, then that way you could have you app updated really downloading files once in a while.

Comment: Or use an XML as Alborz and me suggested earlier :)

Comment: but again it will have internet dependency.What can i do to avoid this?

Comment: Store the XML locally, and just update it when necessary, there's no way you could update your data without a) Internet b) Update from the entire app (which would use internet)